# Why cant I access $_SESSION[USERID]?

Tags: php, javascript, json, session, smarty

When i embed an html page in an iframe on a .tpl file, can I access smarty session variables such as $_SESSION[USERID]? I am trying to figure out why I cant get a userID because I am doing it the same way I have done it before. Are there any restrictions of javascript or json encoding on $_SESSION[USERID]?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $_SESSION['USERID']   ?

Comment: @Nick ODell: A stray identifier will be converted into a string with the content of the value of the identifier. Try it. (it generates a notice, though)

Comment: @Nick ODell: I have tried that way as well anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `session_start()` at the top of the page where u want to retrieve the **$_SESSION** variable

i think in smarty you can get the session data like this

```
$smarty.session.USERID
```